# Page redirects to PHP instead of html page

Tags: php, html, css

So here is my PHP, as you can see I have it redirecting to a file in my server /thanks.html, but when I submit my form it redirects to the PHP file instead of my HTML file. Not really sure what is going on, I know not to use an echo.

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "brettkessler1@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
$subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Write a subject");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$website  = check_input($_POST['website']);
$likeit   = check_input($_POST['likeit']);
$how_find = check_input($_POST['how']);
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "BRANDUO MESSAGE!!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
URL: $website

Like the website? $likeit
How did he/she find it? $how_find

Comments:
$comments

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header("Location:/thanks.html");
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from [PHP header reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Note:
>   Most contemporary clients accept relative URIs as argument to » Location:, but some older clients require an absolute URI including the scheme, hostname and absolute path. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

And, here is a simplified version of the example they give...

```
 /* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
 $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $extra = 'mypage.php';
 header("Location: http://$host/$extra");
 exit;
```

Comment: I have siteground and this is what they recommend:

Comment: Like they say fron your link `header('Location: http://www.domain.com/thanks.html');` is what you're aiming for. You can replace the domain.com with your actual domain or you can insert the info from `$_SERVER`. With things like this if you're getting the same error it could be that the redirect is in your cache so try clearing cache, restarting browser. Or just check the redirect in a different browser.

Comment: ...but if you use variables it has to be `"` as in my answer, not the `'` that you can use if you type the actual URL in there.

Comment: I tried updating the link to header('Location: http://www.domain.com/thanks.html'); checking it in a different browser and clearing the chache, Still the same problem.....if you want to see it perform the problem happens when I submit the form on this page. www.branduodesign.com/contact.html

Comment: Are you starting the page with a `<html>`? If you've written anything to the browser when it gets down to the redirect, the redirect won't work. You have to start writing to the page after the redirect, there can't be any HTML or echoing before it.

Comment: The page starts like this:

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

Comment: This page is a php document that doesn't have any other HTML markup in it if that is what you're asking, I'm linking to is from my HTML page.

Comment: Right, that will stop your redirect from working. Put that inside your `show_error` function where you have a duplicate `<html>` tag.

Comment: Ok so delete the HTML, head and meta tag at the top, and move them to the duplicate section? or just delete the HTML and move the head and meta to the duplicate section. Sorry for all the questions, I am trying to learn this PHP stuff and it's confusing.

Comment: There should be no HTML at the top of your PHP file for the redirect to work. `<!doctype html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Untitled Document</title> </head> <body>` should replace the `<html><body>` inside your error function.

Answer (score 0):

If thanks.html is in same directory as that of this php file, try removing "/" from infront of thanks.html.

i.e try with header("Location: thanks.html");